# Invoke SAP Data Services Web Service using VBA script

Tags: excel, xml, vba, sap-data-services

I'm trying to execute an SAP Data Services job which was published as a Web Service with the session security turned off. I followed one of the blogs and wrote the below VBA script. However, this does not execute the job.

```
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Set ObjHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    sURL = "https://SERVERNAME:PORT/DataServices/servlet/webservices?ver=2.1&label=cm047_extract&wsdlxml"
    sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<ser:RunBatchJobRequest>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<jobName>SAMPLE_JOB</jobName>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<repoName>DS1_REPO_LOCL11</repoName>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<jobServer>Job_Server04</jobServer>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<jobParameters>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<job_system_profile>Dev_Config</job_system_profile>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</jobParameters>"
    sEnv = sEnv & ""
    sEnv = sEnv & "</ser:RunBatchJobRequest>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"
    ObjHTTP.Open "Post", sURL, False
    ObjHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=\'utf-8\'"
    ObjHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "job=SAMPLE_JOB"
    ObjHTTP.send (sEnv)
    MsgBox ObjHTTP.responseText
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R8").Value = ObjHTTP.responseText
    Set ObjHTTP = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're trying to compile XML you will need to include proper spacing.

Comment: Correction - Try adding a namespace definition for ser i.e. xmlns:ser="..." to soap:Envelope element. –